# Extract not-nullable type definition from nullable type

Tags: typescript, types, null, typescript-generics

Let's say I have the following interface generated by an external tool:

```js
interface Animals {
    turtle: { shellHardness: number };
    fox: { whatDidItSay: string } | null;
}
```

I would like to define (extract from `Animals`) a type for both the turtle and the fox but without the `…| null` for the fox. It is easy for the turtle because there is no null:

```js
type Turtle = Animals["turtle"];
```

But how do I do it for the fox? I imagined there could be some `ExtractNullable` type that would remove the nullability:

```
type Fox = ExtractNullable<Animals, "fox">;
```

Unfortunately I was unable to define the `ExtractNullable` type properly. I tried the following:

```
type ExtractNullable<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends null ? never : T[K];
```

…but it did not work. TypeScript playground still gives me that the `Fox` type is defined as `type Fox = { whatTheySaid: string; } | null` instead of `type Fox = { whatTheySaid: string; }`

Is this possible? What am I getting wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[NonNullable<Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype)

```
type Fox = NonNullable<Animals["fox"]>;
```

implementation:

```
/**
 * Exclude null and undefined from T
 */
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```